# How can I skip duplicate board states in N-Queen problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, backtracking, n-queens

I have written some code which runs fine except the fact that it is also finding duplicate board states. I want to have minimal changes in my code so that it can find only unique board states. I'm pasting my code below:

```
class Solution {
    
    List<List<String>> arrangements = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public List<List<String>> solveNQueens(int n) {
        int visited[][] = new int[n][n];
        char board[][] = new char[n][n];
        solve(board,visited,0);
        return arrangements;
    }
    
    public boolean solve(char board[][], int visited[][], int queens) {
        if(queens == board.length) {
            return true;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if(visited[i][j] == 0) {
                    changePosition(visited,i,j,1); //set
                    board[i][j] = 'Q';
                    if(solve(board,visited,queens+1)) {
                        save(board);
                    }
                    changePosition(visited,i,j,-1); // unset
                    board[i][j] = '.';
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public void save(char board[][]) {
        List<String> state = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            String row = "";
            for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
                if(board[i][j] == 'Q'){
                    row += 'Q';
                }else{
                    row += '.';
                }
            }
            state.add(row);
        }
        arrangements.add(state);
    }
    
    public void changePosition(int visited[][], int i, int j, int val) {
        // setting the column
        for(int k = 0; k < visited.length; k++) {
            visited[k][j] += val;
        }
        visited[i][j] -= val;
        //setting the row
        for(int k = 0; k < visited.length; k++) {
            visited[i][k] += val;
        }
        visited[i][j] -= val;
        //setting 1 diagonal
        int a = i, b = j;
        while(a < visited.length && b < visited.length) {
            visited[a][b] += val;
            a++;
            b++;
        }
        visited[i][j] -= val;
        a = i;
        b = j;
        while(a >= 0 && b >= 0) {
            visited[a][b] += val;
            a--;
            b--;
        }
        visited[i][j] -= val;
        //setting 2nd diagonal
        a = i;
        b = j;
        while(a < visited.length && b >= 0) {
            visited[a][b] += val;
            a++;
            b--;
        }
        visited[i][j] -= val;
        a = i;
        b = j;
        while(a >=0 && b < visited.length) {
            visited[a][b] += val;
            a--;
            b++;
        }
    }
}
```

The function `solveNQueens` returns all valid board states in the form of a `List` of board states (a board state in represented in from of a `List` of rows which are represented using `String`). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that for each queen, you try all possible board positions. This means that for `n` queens, every solution will be repeated `n!` times (the number of times the `n` queens can be permutated among the queen positions in the solution).

We can see this from the number of solutions your program finds for each `n` ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Counting_solutions)):

- `n=4`: There are `2` solutions, but your program finds `48 = 2*4! = 2*24` solutions.
- `n=5`: There are `10` solutions, but your program finds `1200 = 10*5!=10*120` solutions.
- `n=6`: There are `4` solutions, but your program finds `2880 = 4*6! = 4*720` solutions.
- ...

This can be fixed easily: Instead of trying all possible board positions for each queen, restrict every queen to a fixed column and only try the positions within this column. This way, no duplicate board positions can be found.

In your `solve` method, remove the inner `for` loop and instead set the `j` coordinate to be the number of the queen (meaning queen 0 will be in column 0, queen 1 will be in column 1, and so on):

```
  public boolean solve(char board[][], int visited[][], int queens) {
    if (queens == board.length) {
      return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      int j = queens;
      ...
```